# Elementary confusion about the universe of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let ${V_0 = \varnothing}$, and recursively define the $\textit{universe of sets}$ by ${V_{n+1} = \mathscr P(V_n)}$. So for example:

$${V_0 = \varnothing}$$
$${V_1 = \{\varnothing}\}$$
$${V_2 = \{ \varnothing,\{\varnothing}\}\}$$
$${V_3 = \{ \varnothing, \{\varnothing \}, \{\{\varnothing}\}\}, \{ \varnothing , \{\varnothing  \} \}\;\}$$

Consider the definition $W_{n + 1} = W_n \cup \mathscr P(W_n)$. This gives rise to the series:

$${W_0 = \varnothing}$$
$${W_1 = W_0 \cup \mathscr P(W_0) =  \{\varnothing},\{ \varnothing\} \}$$
$${W_2 = W_1 \cup \mathscr P(W_1) = \{ \varnothing},\{ \varnothing \} \}\cup \{ \{ \varnothing \}, \{\{\varnothing \} \}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing \}  \} \; \}$$

It seems that $V_1 \neq W_1$. $W_1 \nsubseteq V_1$ since $\{ \varnothing\}\in W_1$, but $\{ \varnothing\}\notin V_1$.
And ${W_2 = \{ \varnothing},\{ \varnothing \} \}\cup \{ \varnothing, \{\varnothing \}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing \}  \} \; \} \neq {V_2 = \{ \varnothing,\{\varnothing}\}\} $.

However, I was told that we can define the universe of sets as $V_0 = \varnothing$ plus either $V_{n + 1} = \mathscr P(V_n)$ or $V_{n + 1} = V_n \cup \mathscr P(V_n)$, with $V_{n + 1}$ being equivalent when defined in either of these ways. But these sets don't seem to be equivalent by the above reasoning.

Where am I getting confused?

Answer (score 3):

You are just not calculating things correctly. For instance, $$W_0\cup \mathcal P(W_0)= \emptyset\cup\{\emptyset\} = \{\emptyset\}$$ When you union with the empty set you add in all elements of the emptyset (that is, nothing), not the empty set itself (you seem to have confused the binary union operation with the pairing operation here). Your $V_3$ is also wrong. It is missing $\{\{\emptyset \}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Definition.** We say that a set $A$ is *transitive* if for all $B\in A$, $B\subseteq A$. In other words, $A\subseteq\mathcal P(A)$.

**Claim.** $A$ is transitive if and only if $A\cup\mathcal P(A)=\mathcal P(A)$.

**Claim.** $\varnothing$ is transitive.

**Claim.** If $A$ is transitive and $X\subseteq\mathcal P(A)$, then $A\cup X$ is transitive. In particular, if $A$ is transitive, $\mathcal P(A)$ is transitive.

---

So, you see, each $V_n$ is transitive, so $\mathcal P(V_n)=V_n\cup\mathcal P(V_n)$.

Comment: That was of no use whatsoever.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I was waiting for three years to hear what you have to say. Glad you finally made it.

Comment: It struck me as banal to say, but I thought I would finally say it.